# Return instead of echo in WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm new to coding so here goes :-).
I'm trying to create a simple plugin for WordPress. The plugin gets data from a MySQL database and echos out a table with the results. My problem is when I use echo the plugin is places first on the page even if i put the shortcode in the middle of the page. I understand that is because I use echo instead of return. I just don't get how to use return in my case. Any help would be much appreciated :-).
Here's my code:

```
    $get_runners = $connection->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, nick_name, FROM database WHERE status = :status ORDER BY first_name ASC');
    $get_runners->execute([status=>'success']);

    // Create the table
    echo '
        <table id="Table" class="start-list-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="start-list-tr">
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Club</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    ';
    // Get the runner object:
    $runners = $get_runners->fetchAll();
    foreach($runners as $runner){
        if($runner->nick_name)
        {
            $runner_name = $runner->first_name.' "'.$runner->nick_name.'" '.$runner->last_name;
        }
        else
        {
            $runner_name = $runner->first_name.' '.$runner->last_name;
        }
        echo '
            <tr class="start-list-tr">
                <td data-label="Name">'.$runner_name.'</td>
                <td data-label="Club">'.$runner->club.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
}
add_shortcode( 'startlist', 'create_startlist' );
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Notes) (emphasis mine): _"**Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.** This is similar to the way filter functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they are called from."_ Is there a reason why you don't return the string of output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign your output to a variable, instead of echoing:

```
$get_runners = $connection->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, nick_name, FROM database WHERE status = :status ORDER BY first_name ASC');
    $get_runners->execute([status=>'success']);


    // Create the table
    $output = '
        <table id="Table" class="start-list-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="start-list-tr">
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Club</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    ';
    // Get the runner object:
    $runners = $get_runners->fetchAll();
    foreach($runners as $runner){
        if($runner->nick_name)
        {
            $runner_name = $runner->first_name.' "'.$runner->nick_name.'" '.$runner->last_name;
        }
        else
        {
            $runner_name = $runner->first_name.' '.$runner->last_name;
        }
        $output .= '
            <tr class="start-list-tr">
                <td data-label="Name">'.$runner_name.'</td>
                <td data-label="Club">'.$runner->club.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>
    </table>';


 return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'startlist', 'create_startlist' );
```

This uses concatenation to continue to fill the variable through your function. You then set the `return` to the `$output` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I just moved the . in the last $output to before the =. (couldn't do it in edit since it was to short :-)).

Comment: I edited it. I can't believe I did that! I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly read more about Shortcodes Output : https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

There are two ways that I can think of at this moment.

Using [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)... basically you need to wrap you code in `ob_start()`

```
function create_startlist() {
    ob_start();
     /* CODE HERE */
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Second is to use a [concatenation operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
function create_startlist() {
    $output = '';
    $output .= 'OUTPUT HERE';
    return $output;
}
```